# How can I call a user-defined method from a widget and forward it to another statefull page

Tags: flutter

I have a "wrapper" that is called at the beginning via the main method. Either the login page or the home page should then be called up in the wrapper depending on the saved "userId". Unfortunately that doesn't work no matter what I do. Sometimes I don't get back the userId from the _getUserId() method.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  var _userId = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder(
    future: _getUserId(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData) {
        print("SNAPSHOT-IF: " + snapshot.data.toString());  //NULL
        return Home(userId: snapshot.data.toString());
      } else {
        print("SNAPSHOT-ELSE: " + snapshot.data.toString());
        return Login();
      }
    }
  );

  Future<String> _getUserId() async {
    await UserPreference().getUser().then((value) async {
      var _currentUserId = value.userId.toString();
      if (_currentUserId.isNotEmpty) {
        await UserPreference().getUserId().then((userId) async {
          _userId = userId.toString();
        });
      }
    });
    return Future<String>.value(_userId.toString());
  }
}
```

Although "snapshot.hasdata" is equal to NULL, this is ignored and the IF area is always called and that several times.

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
I/flutter (16748): SNAPSHOT-IF: null
Reloaded 1 of 1193 libraries in 1.017ms.
I/flutter (16748): SNAPSHOT-IF: null
```

How can I now call the pages from the Wrapper depending on the existing userId? Is there any other way besides using Futurebuilder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you can add this kind of method to your splash screen. Because every time state change `FutureBuilder` is running. even when you are in HomePage

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrappereState extends State<Wrapper> {
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    findWrapper();
  }

    Future<String> findWrapper() async {
    String _userId;
    var data = await UserPreference().getUser();
    if(data?.userId != null) {
      _userId = await UserPreference().getUserId();
    }
    if(_userId != null){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home(userId:_userId)));
    }else{
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => //add any loading widget until find path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the better way to check which page should be open

Here is the Code for the stateful widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder(
          stream: JsonWebToken.jwtOrEmpty.asStream(),//You can use your own function
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: !snapshot.hasData
                    ?
               
                 Login()
                    :
           
               Home(userId: snapshot.data.toString())
                ,
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('error Occurred');
            }
            else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());}
          }));
}
```

In a login() page . you should put this code in at the end of onpressed  **sigin** button

```
Navigator.pop(context);
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper ()),
```

so by doing it will build your wrapper widget again it will check for data in stream builder so you will reach your preferred page according to conditions

Comment: Hi, Many Thanks for your help. I've come a little further. I now have two problems:
1. the get method "_getUserId" is not recognized. I have renamed the name to "getUserId". This is also not recognized, but I don't get an error message. 2. After a logout (await UserSecurePreference (). RemoveUser ();) I don't see any changes. Only after a hot restart do I get the login page. Do I have to work with StreamBuilder at this point too? How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Provide your logout code. and also Home(), class

Comment: Hi, thanks. My Home class is at the time a Satefull Widget File with a Drawer on the left. In this Drawer I have a ListView with a "Logout" option: `
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
              onTap: () async {
                await UserSecurePreference().removeUser(); 
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper()),
                );
              },`

Comment: Did you still stuck in logout?

Comment: Hi, no, because I have still problems with the login and I don't exactly know how the flutter_secure_storage works. I log in and save the user data and go to my Home.dart with 'Navigator.pushReplacement (... Home.dart)'. But when I try to forward to the home page via my wrapper "Navigator.pushReplacement (... wrapper.dart)", my "Widget build (BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder" doesn't work anymore and I stay at the login page . It seems, the IF-area is not called although the user data is saved beforehand.

Comment: Actually, you need to create one stateful widget with Stream builder and inside StreamBuilder there should be  a scaffold, now inside that scaffold body you will have to set a check i.e: if(login==true) return Home() else return Login()  and inside.

Comment: Hi, thanks, my "login == false or true" is my userId in MyPersonalData. If there is a userId, the home page should be called otherwise Login. The problem is that StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder are totally unpredictable. Both are called several times and chance decides whether the IF or ELSE area is called.

Comment: I Have updated my answer you should see it.   I am personally using that code in my app  and it works perfectly

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. But the Stream- and FutureBuilder are wrong approaches for me. I only need a userId once. These two run several times and in the meantime is the wrong page called with wrong data. I no longer use these approaches and I call the userId directly in "initState" and then forward the page with the correct userId without Stream- or FutureBuilder but with Future.delayed.

Comment: yes, You must use it with intestate when the app launches the first time. But questions don't describe it